# Remapping all OSX shortcuts from cmd to ctrl

Tags: macos, command-line, vim

I am new to OSX, and since I have mapped CTRL to CapsLock, and use alt a lot, I dont need CMD,
how to remap all shortcuts globally not to use CMD?

Comment: That's a pretty fundamental change...why have you remapped CTRL to Caps Lock??

Comment: Why don't you then map CMD to CapsLock?

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't be usable in practice:

- There are many shortcuts that include both control and command (like ⌃⌘F for toggling full screen)
- It's useful to have both ⌘C and ⌃C in terminals
- You couldn't use the emacs-style keybindings in text views
- Safari and Chrome use control and option as modifier keys for access keys

The shortcuts of menu items can be changed in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shorcuts. But it can't be used with menu items whose name changes dynamically or shortcuts that don't have menu items. And it doesn't work with some cross-platform applications.

I can't think of any practical way to do it with [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) either.

Comment: The reason why I want to achieve this is that I use to emacs shortcuts in terminal, with cmd it is hard to get alt, but maybe I will need to get use to it...

Comment: Actually I do something similar with KeyRemap4MacBook. You can set Application specific remaps. Also it's possible to have them device specific. So I remap only in Terminal, Emacs, Windows Remote Desktop. But leave the default behavior in other apps.

Comment: I will try to do it, and I will see how it is working...

Comment: @Sławosz I don't see how pressing either cmd+alt or ctrl+alt would be any level of difficulty...

Comment: @demure it is not confortable for me since I get used to emacs shortcuts.